# Como enviar o resultado de uma query via email

Tags: sql, oracle

Gostaria de saber se alguém saberia me informar como posso fazer para executar a query a baixo corretamente.
Preciso que isso seja enviado para o e-mail aparecendo o resultado que no caso seria Nome : Ariel

```
[select rtstr1 as hostname
   from poldat_view
  where poldat_view.polcod = 'VAR-EXEL'
    and poldat_view.polvar = 'EMAIL'
    and poldat_view.polval = 'SMTP-SERVER'
    and wh_id = '0028'] catch(510, -1403)
|
[select 'Ariel.silva@teste.com' as to_email
   from dual
 |
        if (@? = 0)
 {
     send email
      where attachment = @file_attachment
        and from = 'do-not-reply@exel.com'
        and msg = [select 'Ariel' as Nome from Dual]
        and to = @to_email
        and subject = 'Relatorio Expedição Norditropin'
        and hostname = @hostname
 }
```

O problema esta no final onde temos "and msg = [select 'Ariel' as Nome from Dual]" o e-mail é enviado porem ao invés de aparecer o resultado da consulta aparece a consulta em si ([select 'Ariel' as Nome from Dual]), já tentei fazer de outras formas e também não surgiu o resultado esperado. agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Você tem de criar um cursor e uma variável (char) e preencher a variável com  o result da query. , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html >